# Overriding window as function call context

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

I am writing test cases in cypress, and every line I write refers to the cy object. A sample of my test code looks something like this:

```
it('does stuff', () => {
    cy.visit(startUrl);
    cy.get(".new-item-button").click();
    cy.url().should('include', url2);
    cy.get(".home-link").click();
    cy.url().should('include', startUrl);
    cy.url().should('not.include', url2);
}
```

Seeing all cy references makes me sad. Is there anyway to make function calls in my test function use a different call context? Just taking cy away would make javascript look for global functions, but is there anyway that I make javascript look for them in the cy object, so that I could write like this?

```
it('does stuff', () => {
    visit(startUrl);
    get(".new-item-button").click();
    url().should('include', url2);
    get(".home-link").click();
    url().should('include', startUrl);
    url().should('not.include', url2
}
```

that would make me feel happier. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since calling a parent command starts a new command, you can actually do this:

```js
it('does stuff', () => { 
cy.visit(startUrl)
.get(".new-item-button").click()
.url().should('include', url2)
.get(".home-link").click()
.url().should('include', startUrl)
.url().should('not.include', url2)
 }
```

Comment: Ooh, it returns `this` from **every** method? Even `.get(".new-item-button").click()`?

Comment: It's Cypress chainers all the way down, and a "parent command" such as `url` effectively starts a new command.

Comment: So, again, you're saying `cy.get(".new-item-button").click()` returns the same value `cy` has? And `.url().should('include', startUrl)` (since you said "`url` effectively starts a new command"). Perhaps you could point to docs on that? Cool if so (though -- like you, I think -- just using the `cy.` seems cleaner to me).

Comment: No, doesn't return the same value, but Cypress interprets it the same way.

Comment: As for why it makes me sad, I have several hundred lines that all start with cy. Maybe its because im not used to it yet, but when i read it, i end up reading the cy part too instead of just reading what the line does.

Sorry about the semicolons, didn't lint this section yet.

Comment: @Fakenick - Don't be sorry about using semicolons rather than relying on automatic semicolon insertion (an error-correction mechanism in the JS parser). It's a style choice (and a better one, IMHO).

Comment: @bkucera - Cool. If it works, that's the main thing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You *can*, if you're not using strict mode, but you probably shouldn't. JavaScript's `with` statement is effectively deprecated because it makes code very unclear (details in [this article](https://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) by Douglas Crockford).

Here's how you'd do it with `with`:

```
// NOT RECOMMENDED, and doesn't work in strict mode
with (cy) {
    visit(startUrl);
    // ...
}
```

`cy.` is already quite short, I'd **strongly recommend** just keeping using it. It's simple, and it's clear to others coming to the code.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is technically correct, but bkucera's answer is closer to what I need, would have accepted both your answers if I could. Thank you for explaining with.

Comment: @Fakenick - No need to apologize! I'm glad Cypress offers that chaining mechanism. As you can tell, I really wouldn't suggest using `with`. :-)